# Where is the data generated by ettercap -T -i wlan0 saved?

Tags: sniffing, ettercap

I executed this command out of curiosity:

```
ettercap -T -i wlan0
```

After a couple of seconds, it started flooding my terminal emulator with loads of data (sniffed data, I guess). I think this data is going into some kind of cache memory or something. I want to know where is this data saved?

Is this data really saved somewhere? Or does it vanish after the operation?

Comment: Do you mean the data used by ettercap or the data generated by ettercap?

Comment: Data generated by ettercap.

Comment: In that case, this question has nothing to do with security. To answer your question, it just gets redirected to stdout(terminal) by default. You can redirect it to a file if you want to save the results

Comment: This means it is never saved anywhere?

Comment: It is not permanently saved anywhere unless you explicitly ask it to.

Comment: It's not redirected to stdout. It used to be in previous versions, not anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per basic bash syntax you can use `ettercap -T -i wlan0 > dump.pcap` to redirect the output to a file instead of printing to stdout.

Comment: Where is this stdout? i am not that good in linux.

Comment: Is it saved somewhere?Is it using memory permanently?

Comment: @SohanArafat stdout just means it is printed to your terminal. It is kept in memory temporarily until that memory gets used up again. Remember that memory vanishes when you reboot too.